# Deriving the closed form of $M_{n+1} =\frac{2^{2n+1}}{M_n}\left(\sqrt{1+ 2^{-2n}M^2_{n}}-1\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, closed-form

I have the sequence, let $M_0=1$

$$M_{n+1} =\frac{2^{2n+1}}{M_n}\left(\sqrt{1+ 2^{-2n}M^2_{n}}-1\right)$$
Which I would like first to study the convergence and fine the closed form. 
 I failed  to show that $M_n$ is bounded and  monotone.

This could be easy if have the explicit expression of it.

> **Question:**
>   Is there a closed a form of this sequence? does anyone has an idea?

**FYI** In the book it is mentioned that this sequence is used to approximate the area of the unit circle. may be some else has a more clever explanation to this connection

Comment: with the change of variable $X_n:=\frac{M_n}{2^n}$ the recurrence "simplifies" to $$X_{n+1}X_n=\sqrt{1+X_n^2}-1$$ However I dont know if this is solvable in closed form.

Comment: Could you give a reference to the book?

Comment: I strongly assume that $4M_n$ is the area of the regular $2^{n+1}$-gon circumscribing the unit disk, compare Figure 1 in http://www.physicsinsights.org/pi_from_pythagoras-1.html.

Comment: @MartinR indeed,  that was related

Comment: @Masacroso there is a closed in fact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer thanks to @Masacroso comment.

> $$M_n = 2^n \tan\left(\frac{π}{2^{n+2}}\right)\to \frac{π}{4}$$
>   and 
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}M_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{π}{4} \frac{\tan\left(\frac{π}{2^{n+2}}\right)}{\frac{π}{2^{n+2}}}=\frac{π}{4}\lim_{x\to 0}  \frac{\tan\left(x\right)}{x} =\frac{π}{4}$$

One can show that $M_n\ge 0,$ let $X_n:=\frac{M_n}{2^n}$ then  $$M_{n+1} =\frac{2^{2n+1}}{M_n}\left(\sqrt{1+ 2^{-2n}M^2_{n}}-1\right)\implies X_{n+1}=\frac{1}{X_n}(\sqrt{1+X_n^2}-1)$$

There exists $a_n\in[0, \frac{π}{2}]$ such that, $$X_n=\tan(a_n)$$

hence we have, 
$$\begin{align}\tan(a_{n+1})= X_{n+1}&=\frac{1}{X_n}\left(\sqrt{1+X_n^2}-1\right) \\&=\frac{1}{\tan(a_n)}\left(\sqrt{1+\tan^2(a_n)}-1\right)\\&= \frac{1}{\tan(a_n)}\left(\frac{1}{\cos(a_n)}-1\right) \\&= \frac{1-\cos(a_n)}{\sin(a_n)} = \frac{1-\cos^2(\frac{a_n}{2})+\sin^2(\frac{a_n}{2})}{2\cos(\frac{a_n}{2})\sin(\frac{a_n}{2})} \ \\&= \frac{1-\cos(a_n)}{\sin(a_n)} = \frac{2\sin^2(\frac{a_n}{2})}{2\cos(\frac{a_n}{2})\sin(\frac{a_n}{2})} \\&=\color{blue}{\tan(\frac{a_n}{2})}\end{align}$$

Finally we have 
$$a_{n+1}= \frac{a_n}{2}\implies a_n=\frac{a_0}{2^{n}} $$

But we have $a_0 = π/4$ therefore we end up, with 
$$M_n = 2^n \tan\left(\frac{π}{2^{n+2}}\right)\to \frac{π}{4}$$

Answer (score 4):

**Incomplete answer** (sorry, going out with my children). It's definitely monotone.
$$\color{red}{M_{n+1}} =\frac{2^{2n+1}}{M_n}\left(\sqrt{1+ 2^{-2n}M^2_{n}}-1\right)=
\frac{2^{n+1}}{M_n}\left(\sqrt{2^{2n}+ M^2_{n}}-2^n\right)=\\
\frac{2^{n+1}}{M_n}\left(\frac{M_n^2}{\sqrt{2^{2n}+ M^2_{n}}+2^n}\right)\color{red}{\leq}
\frac{2^{n+1}}{M_n}\left(\frac{M_n^2}{2^{n+1}}\right)=\color{red}{M_n}$$
and $M_n>0$ should be easy to show.

Answer (score 2):

Define $a_n = \dfrac{M_n}{2^n} \ (n \in \mathbb{N}_+)$, then$$
a_{n + 1} = \frac{\sqrt{1 + a_n^2} - 1}{a_n} > 0.
$$
Define $b_n = \sqrt{1 + a_n^2} \ (n \in \mathbb{N}_+)$, then$$
b_n > 1 \Longrightarrow a_n = \sqrt{b_n^2 - 1},
$$
and\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{\Longrightarrow}}\sqrt{b_{n + 1}^2 - 1} = \frac{b_n - 1}{\sqrt{b_n^2 - 1}} = \sqrt{\frac{b_n - 1}{b_n + 1}}\\
&\Longrightarrow b_{n + 1}^2 = \frac{b_n - 1}{b_n + 1} + 1 = \frac{2b_n}{b_n + 1}.
\end{align*}
Define $c_n = \dfrac{1}{b_n} \ (n \in \mathbb{N}_+)$, then$$
c_{n + 1}^2 = \frac{1 + c_n}{2}.
$$

Because $c_1 = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}} < 1$, denote $θ = \arccos \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$, then by induction on $n$, there is $0 < c_n < 1$. Define $θ_n = \arccos c_n \ (n \in \mathbb{N}_+)$, then$$
\cos θ_{n + 1} = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos θ_n}{2}} = \cos \frac{θ_n}{2} \Longrightarrow θ_{n + 1} = \frac{θ_n}{2}.
$$
Therefore, $θ_n = \dfrac{θ}{2^{n - 1}} \ (n \in \mathbb{N}_+)$, which implies$$
M_n = 2^n \tan \frac{θ}{2^{n - 1}}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Convergence :**
$$
M_{n+1} =\frac{2^{2n+1}}{M_n}\left(\sqrt{1+ 2^{-2n}M^2_{n}}-1\right)
$$
$$
=>(\frac{M_{n+1}M_n}{2^{2n+1}}+1)^2=1+ 2^{-2n}M^2_{n}
$$
On Solving,
$$
(\frac{M_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}})^2+\frac{M_{n+1}}{M_n}=1
$$
As $(\frac{M_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}})^2 > 0$ ($M_n>0$ for all $n\geq1$). So, $(\frac{M_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}})^2+\frac{M_{n+1}}{M_n}>\frac{M_{n+1}}{M_n}$ which implies $1>\frac{M_{n+1}}{M_n}$. Hence, we get $M_n>M_{n+1}$.

**Closed Form:**
I am not able to find the closed form. I also try it with Wolfram Alpha but it doesn't work.